# How to update the index value in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddl

PFB my table structure

```
App id name
----- ------
1      Agile 
4      sdlc
```

While entering data in above tables I wrongly entered some data twice. The index values has been changed to 4 instead of 2.

But I need the below index order

```
App id name
----- ------
1      Agile 
2      sdlc
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Assuming `app_id` is the primary  key of the table there is no sense in changing the value. The PK value has **no** meaning whatsover. `4` is just as good for a PK value as `3462373276`

Comment: Assuming that what you mean by *index* is really the **identity** value in a SQL Server table - check out this blog post: [Stop making assumptions about `IDENTITY`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-making-assumptions-about-identity), stop worrying about gaps - they are really **NOT** a problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [App ID] in a UI and are concerned that users will highlight gaps in the values between records, then you shouldn't be using an identity column in this way.  It's probably best you rethink your design and what you are trying to achieve.  You could use an int column, or even a varchar, that you control yourself while using a primary key constraint.